# UITapGesture to make view full screen not reversing

Tags: swift

I have a `textView` that I'd like to make fullscreen upon a tap and then back to its original size if tapped again. I can get it to full screen but not back to original size.

Here's what I have - can you help me understand why this doesn't work?

```
let viewWidth = view.frame.width
let viewHeight = view.frame.height
let textViewWidth = textView.frame.width
let textViewHeight = textView.frame.height
if sender.state == .ended {
    let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 0.5, curve: .easeInOut, animations: {
        sender.view!.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: viewWidth, height: viewHeight)
    })
    animator.startAnimation()
} else if sender.state == .began {
    let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 0.5, curve: .easeInOut, animations: {
    sender.view!.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: textViewWidth, height: textViewHeight)
    })
        animator.startAnimation()
}
```

Updated as recommended:

```
    var textViewHeight = Int()
    var textViewWidth = Int()

//Mark: - Get initial value of textViewWidth and Height
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        let widthOfTextView = textView.frame.width
        textViewWidth = Int(widthOfTextView) 
        let heightOfTextView = textView.frame.height
        textViewHeight = Int(heightOfTextView) 
    }

//Mark: - UITapGestureRecognized for hiding Toolbar, Status&Navigation Bar, slider
    @objc func textViewTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        toolbar.isHidden = toolbar.isHidden ? false : true
        textSlider.isHidden = textSlider.isHidden ? false : true
        navigationController!.setNavigationBarHidden(!isHidden, animated: false)
        isHidden = navigationController!.isNavigationBarHidden
        self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()

        let viewWidth = view.frame.width
    let viewHeight = view.frame.height
    //let textViewWidth = textView.frame.width
    //let textViewHeight = textView.frame.height
    if textView.frame.width == view.frame.width {
        // text view is full size, animate back to normal size
        let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 0.5, curve: .easeInOut, animations: {
            sender.view!.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.textViewWidth, height: self.textViewHeight)
        })
        animator.startAnimation()
    } else {
        // text view is normal size, animate to full size
        let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 0.5, curve: .easeInOut, animations: {
            sender.view!.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: viewWidth, height: viewHeight)
        })
        animator.startAnimation()
    }
}
```

Here's a screenrecording of what's happening. After I reverse the textView back to its original size, it ends up higher than its original position - https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmYBE.jpg

Comment: Check its going inside the else part or not also check the textViewWidth and height its proper or not ?

Comment: @vivekDas else is not being called. Is that because I have the wrong state?

Comment: why using sender.state? Can use one bool value like isFullScreen. Set it to false initially, then on tap check the bool value if it is false then show in full screen if true reverse the size. And at last set bool like isFullScreen = !isFullScreen.